# Crappy adware in my chrome browser when on websites with jw player

Tags: google-chrome

Hello people i just wanted to know whether anyone can tell me how to remove jwplayer or disable it in chrome. I find it quite annoying that people can just embed ads into the buttons. By disabling jwplayer i will be able to force chrome int using the default. thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `jwplayer`?

Comment: @Pilot6 JW Player is a Flash video player that owners of web-sites install on their server for video playback. If the site uses JW Player it'll probably mention JW Player or Longtail when you right-click on the video.

Comment: You can always remove it from Chrome. It is not Ubuntu related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go into your Chrome extensions and plugin settings and remove JWPlayer or Longtail from the installation.

Worst case, you just remove `~/.config/google-chrome` and start over with a fresh profile, since that'll erase any installed plugins on Chrome as well.

After that's done, you should no longer have issues with jwplayer adware.